# Crash a kernel on purpose

Tags: windows, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there any way I can crash a kernel on purpose (e.g., kernel panic, blue screen, black screen, or whatever). Assume I can change any registers and have administrative privilege of the system. I would like to demonstrate this on both Windows and Linux platforms.

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: You should look into [fork bombs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/)

Comment: check for crash https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, you must compile the kernel with the CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ option, then you can crash the kernel by writing the **c**rash command into `/proc/sysrq-trigger`, or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
See the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) for details.

In Windows, you must set the `CrashOnCtrlScroll` registry key for the keyboard driver, and reboot, then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> to crash the kernel.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Write your own kernel module and load it, make sure you call `BUG()` or `BUG_ON()`.
2. Use sysrq; `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, with this make sure to install kdump if you are interested in capturing a vmcore file.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo c > proc/sysrq-trigger
```